# Run docker container on specific drive

Tags: docker, containers, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have docker desktop on C drive also as WSL. I started ubuntu terminal on F drive in specific folder by making it starting location. After executing `docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started` it says me ```unable to find image <image_name> and starts container.[image]
[image]

After that when container is created I can see it in docker.

It also creates image but the problem is I can't find it and where image and container are stored.

How can I find files of docker and so on and create, run container with its image on F drive in wsl folder (in this example)?

Answer (score 0):

well i can't understand your problem well, but here an answer for your question

> It also creates image but the problem is I can't find it and where image and container are stored.

to find images downloaded locally
run

```
docker images
```

to find the metadata which include path of stored image

```
docker inspect <image_name>
```

Comment: The problem is I can't create image and run container on F disk partition. I tried to use WSL and start in specific directory on F as you can see but docker says me no. Well I want to find way to move all of it to other place.

Comment: `mnt/f/wsl` where `f` is name of partition. That's directory where I want to start container and store image.